# Mailchimp Oauth2 sample app troubleshooting

Tags: php, yii2, mailchimp, oauth-2.0

I keep getting the following error when I try to use the Mailchimp OAUTH2 sample app (PHP).

For your reference, here's their github repo: https://github.com/mailchimp/OAuth2-sample-apps

However, my client id and client secret are correct (have copied and pasted them multiple times).

```
Complete Failure!: redirect_uri_mismatch

This likely means that you have entered a bad client_id or client_secret or you are being awesome and checking to see this failure occur. 

Try Again?
```

If it helps, I'm using the Yii 2 framework.

Comment: Have you tried using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Mailchimp doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: You'll probably have to supply your actual code, then, because otherwise there's really no way to help you. The sample app you linked to is not working code, the Oauth2 Client class needs to be edited to contain your client secret, client id, and redirect url. It seems likely that one of those three has been entered incorrectly, likely the redirect URL.

Comment: yes i agree with @TooMuchPete you should share the actual code for `Oauth2Client` class you are using after the updates