# MailChimp OAuth2 Access Token

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, yii2, mailchimp

This question is similar to others that have already been asked, but the answers haven't helped and there's a key piece that I think is missing.  I'm at step 4 of the MailChimp OAuth2 flow, which requires an out-of-band post to the authorize url ([see here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/)).  It keeps returning the error: invalid_grant, which I understand can indicate a number of different errors.  Here's my code (I'm using Yii2).

```
// Controller action (authorize)
public function actionMailchimpAuthorize()
{
    $redirect_uri = Url::toRoute(['controller/mailchimp-token'], 'https');
    $base_uri = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize';
    $params = '?response_type=code&client_id=' . Model::CLIENT_ID . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($redirect_uri);
    $authorize_uri = $base_uri . $params;

    return $this->render('mailchimpAuthorize', [
        'authorize_uri' => $authorize_uri,
    ]);
}

// Controller action (token)
public function actionMailchimpToken($code=NULL)
{
        $redirect_uri = Url::toRoute(['controller/mailchimp-token'], 'https');
        $token_uri = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token';
        $params = [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => Model::CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret' => Model::CLIENT_SECRET,
            'redirect_uri' => urlencode($redirect_uri),
            'code' => $code,
        ];
        $user_agent = 'oauth2-draft-v10';
        $headers = ['Accept: application/json'];
        $res = Utility::post($token_uri, $params, $user_agent, $headers);
        var_dump($res);
}

// Utility
 public function post($url, $params, $user_agent = NULL, $headers = NULL)
{
        $ch = curl_init($url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $post = http_build_query($params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        isset($user_agent) ? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent) : NULL;
        isset($headers) ? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers) : NULL;
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $res;   
}
```

Answers here on SO make a big deal about the redirect URIs matching.  But there are three places to enter a return uri: In Mailchimp when you register the app, in the authorization url, and the token url.  Do all three need to macth exactly, or only the auth and token URIs?  I've tried various combinations to no avail. My problem may be something different, but this the only thing that I'm unclear about (I think). As with many before me, I'm going crazy with this one.

Comment: have you got it working with the default [**`php`**](https://github.com/mailchimp/OAuth2-sample-apps/tree/master/php5) library provided by MailChimp.

Comment: No, I tried it but ran into other problems.  I've also tried Yii's auth manager.  Direct coding is the most straightforward and has gotten me the furthest.

Comment: I ran into this problem with the sample library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645238/mailchimp-oauth2-sample-app-troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution was provided to me by another developer.

commmon/components/Mailchimp.php:

```
namespace common\components;

class Mailchimp extends \yii\authclient\OAuth2 
{
    public $clientId = 'client id';
    public $clientSecret = 'client secret';
    public $authUrl = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize';
    public $tokenUrl = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token';

    // min function needed to extend – just put the return to true as I don’t care the return value
    public function initUserAttributes()
    {
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionMailchimpAuthorize()
{
    $oauthClient = new \common\components\Mailchimp();
    $oauthClient->setReturnUrl(Url::toRoute(['controller/mailchimp-complete'], 'https));
    $url = $oauthClient->buildAuthUrl();
    $response = Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url);

    return $this->render('mailchimpAuthorize');
}

public function actionMailchimpComplete()
{
    $code = Yii::$app->getRequest()->get('code');
    $oauthClient = new \common\components\Mailchimp();
    $oauthClient->setReturnUrl(Url::toRoute(['controller/mailchimp-complete'], 'https));
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->fetchAccessToken($code);

    // Complete MC flow with request to metadata url
    $headers = [                                                                                
        'User-Agent:oauth2-draft-v10', 
        'Host:login.mailchimp.com', 
        'Accept:application/json', 
        'Authorization:OAuth ' . $oauthClient->getAccessToken()->token
    ];
    $url = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata';
    $res = Utility::get($url, $headers);
    $dc = json_decode($res)->dc;   // retrieve datacenter

    return $this->render('mailchimpComplete', ['accessToken' => $accessToken, 'data' => $oauthClient]);     
}

// save token-datacenter to database for making api calls
```

View file mailchimpComplete.php:

```
echo($data->getAccessToken()->token);
```

The return URI set at app registration in Mailchimp is the same as listed above: https://myhost.com/controller/mailchimp-complete